# TF 2.0 Error: Gradients does not exist for variables during training using gradienttape

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I tried to make a class using batchnormalization layer from tf 2.0, however it gave me an error that Gradients does not exist for variables. I tried to use batchnormalization directly but it gave me the same error as well. it seems like it is not traing the variable related to the batchnormalization step.

I tried to use model.trainable_variables instead of model.variables but it didn't work either.

```py
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from scipy import ndimage

learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100

tf.random.set_seed(777)

cur_dir = os.getcwd()
ckpt_dir_name = 'checkpoints'
model_dir_name = 'minst_cnn_best'

checkpoint_dir = os.path.join(cur_dir, ckpt_dir_name, model_dir_name)
os.makedirs(checkpoint_dir, exist_ok=True)

checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, model_dir_name)



mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images.astype(np.float32) /255.
test_images = test_images.astype(np.float32) /255.
print(train_images.shape, test_images.shape)
train_images = np.expand_dims(train_images, axis = -1)
test_images = np.expand_dims(test_images, axis = -1)
print(train_images.shape, test_images.shape)

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels, 10)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels, 10)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, 
                                                    train_labels)).shuffle(buffer_size = 100000).batch(batch_size)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, 
                                                    test_labels)).batch(batch_size)

class ConvBNRelu(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='SAME'):
        super(ConvBNRelu, self).__init__()
        self.conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides, 
                                        padding=padding, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')
        self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        layer = self.conv(inputs)
        layer = self.batchnorm(layer)
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
        return layer    

class DenseBNRelu(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units):
        super(DenseBNRelu, self).__init__()
        self.dense = keras.layers.Dense(units=units, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')
        self.batchnorm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        layer = self.dense(inputs)
        layer = self.batchnorm(layer)
        layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
        return layer

class MNISTModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MNISTModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = ConvBNRelu(filters=32, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding='SAME')        
        self.pool1 = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding='SAME')
        self.conv2 = ConvBNRelu(filters=64, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding='SAME')
        self.pool2 = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding='SAME')
        self.conv3 = ConvBNRelu(filters=128, kernel_size=[3, 3], padding='SAME')
        self.pool3 = keras.layers.MaxPool2D(padding='SAME')
        self.pool3_flat = keras.layers.Flatten()
        self.dense4 = DenseBNRelu(units=256)
        self.drop4 = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.4)
        self.dense5 = keras.layers.Dense(units=10, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal')
    def call(self, inputs, training=False):
        net = self.conv1(inputs)        
        net = self.pool1(net)
        net = self.conv2(net)
        net = self.pool2(net)
        net = self.conv3(net)
        net = self.pool3(net)
        net = self.pool3_flat(net)
        net = self.dense4(net)
        net = self.drop4(net)
        net = self.dense5(net)
        return net

models = []
num_models = 5
for m in range(num_models):
    models.append(MNISTModel())

def loss_fn(model, images, labels):
    logits = model(images, training=True)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,
                                                               labels=labels))
    return loss   

def grad(model, images, labels):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = loss_fn(model, images, labels)
    return tape.gradient(loss, model.variables)

def evaluate(models, images, labels):
    predictions = np.zeros_like(labels)
    for model in models:
        logits = model(images, training=False)
        predictions += logits
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions, 1), tf.argmax(labels, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    return accuracy

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = learning_rate)


checkpoints = []
for m in range(num_models):
    checkpoints.append(tf.train.Checkpoint(cnn=models[m]))


for epoch in range(training_epochs):
    avg_loss = 0.
    avg_train_acc = 0.
    avg_test_acc = 0.
    train_step = 0
    test_step = 0    

    for images, labels in train_dataset:
        for model in models:
            grads = grad(model, images, labels)                
            optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables))            
            loss = loss_fn(model, images, labels)
            avg_loss += loss / num_models
        acc = evaluate(models, images, labels)
        avg_train_acc += acc
        train_step += 1
    avg_loss = avg_loss / train_step
    avg_train_acc = avg_train_acc / train_step

    for images, labels in test_dataset:        
        acc = evaluate(models, images, labels)        
        avg_test_acc += acc
        test_step += 1    
    avg_test_acc = avg_test_acc / test_step    

    print('Epoch:', '{}'.format(epoch + 1), 'loss =', '{:.8f}'.format(avg_loss), 
          'train accuracy = ', '{:.4f}'.format(avg_train_acc), 
          'test accuracy = ', '{:.4f}'.format(avg_test_acc))


    for idx, checkpoint in enumerate(checkpoints):
        checkpoint.save(file_prefix=checkpoint_prefix+'-{}'.format(idx))

print('Learning Finished!')
```

W0727 20:27:05.344142 140332288718656 optimizer_v2.py:982] Gradients does not exist for variables ['mnist_model/conv_bn_relu/batch_normalization/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model/conv_bn_relu/batch_normalization/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model/conv_bn_relu_1/batch_normalization_1/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model/conv_bn_relu_1/batch_normalization_1/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model/conv_bn_relu_2/batch_normalization_2/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model/conv_bn_relu_2/batch_normalization_2/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model/dense_bn_relu/batch_normalization_3/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model/dense_bn_relu/batch_normalization_3/moving_variance:0'] when minimizing the loss.
W0727 20:27:05.407717 140332288718656 deprecation.py:323] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:460: BaseResourceVariable.constraint (from tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Apply a constraint manually following the optimizer update step.
W0727 20:27:05.499249 140332288718656 optimizer_v2.py:982] Gradients does not exist for variables ['mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_3/batch_normalization_4/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_3/batch_normalization_4/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_4/batch_normalization_5/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_4/batch_normalization_5/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_5/batch_normalization_6/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model_1/conv_bn_relu_5/batch_normalization_6/moving_variance:0', 'mnist_model_1/dense_bn_relu_1/batch_normalization_7/moving_mean:0', 'mnist_model_1/dense_bn_relu_1/batch_normalization_7/moving_variance:0'] when minimizing the loss.
...

Comment: welcome to SO! , please read [mcve] and edit post accordingly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch Normalization doesn't have gradient in tensorflow 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434653/batch-normalization-doesnt-have-gradient-in-tensorflow-2-0)

Answer (score 4):

You're computing the gradient of the loss with respect to the `model.variables`: this collection contains not only the trainable variables (the model weights) but also the non-trainable variables like the moving mean and variance computed by the batch normalization layer.

You have to compute the gradient with respect to the `trainable_variables`. In short change the lines

```
 return tape.gradient(loss, model.variables)
```

and

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables))
```

to

```
 return tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
```

and

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
```

Comment: Those parameters are not trainable only in eval mode. during training they need to be able to be trained unless they are frozen. am I missing something here?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing something :) During the training phase, these variables (moving mean, moving variance) needs to be updatable (not trainable!), but no gradient is flowing through them. These variables are not updated using gradient descent, they just receive an update with a new value (but this is not a training, this is just a usual variable update)

Comment: are you sure? we do calculate the backward pass for BN layer as well, the gradient need to flow through them! the gamma and beta are trained with sgd. [have a look here](https://kratzert.github.io/2016/02/12/understanding-the-gradient-flow-through-the-batch-normalization-layer.html).

Comment: Yes of course, but in the model we have both: gamma, beta, and moving_mean and moving_variane. In the model.trainable_variables collection you have the beta and gamma variables, but the moving mean and moving variance that you collect during the training, are stored in the model.variables collection - these are the non-trainable parameters that you only update each training step with the moving mean/variance formula.

Comment: import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Input((100)), tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()]
)

print("All the model variables")
print(model.variables)
print("Trainable variables only")
print(model.trainable_variables)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification nessuno. I had the impression, we were talking about the gamma and beta and you saying there is no sgd for bn params at all. (by params I meant learnable parameters gamma and beta) . thanks to you its all fine now. really appreciate you taking the time to clarify this.

Comment: oh, silly me! I see it now, I completely missed your emphasis on the moving averages!